# In My shell when i run that Script it show error and when i use ipdb it show me error on in line 30 TimeoutException: TimeoutException()

Tags: python, django, selenium

I use that script for WhatsApp integration with my website in python. 
Why My that Script is not working can you please check here in contact i maintain my contactfile and when use ipdb for trace code it show me error in line 30.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)


with open("contact") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            name = (line.rstrip('\n'))
            text = """Hello {}, My name is Rhevin
            Have a good day :)
                """.format(name)
            print 'Harish'
            inp_xpath_search = "//input[@title='Search or start new chat']"
            input_box_search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH, inp_xpath_search)))
            print '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@',input_box_search
            input_box_search.send_keys(name + Keys.ENTER)
            #x_arg_contact = '//div[@class="chat-title"]'

            x_arg_contact = '//span[contains(@title,' + name + ')]'
            input_box_contact = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH, x_arg_contact)))
            print '-------------------',input_box_contact
            inp_xpath = "//div[@contenteditable='true']"    
            input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
            print '+++++++++++++++++++++++',input_box
            input_box.send_keys(text + Keys.ENTER)
            print '==============================='
            time.sleep(5)
            print("send")
        except:
            print("error")
```

Comment: Not sure what line 30 is, but you get a timeout exception probably at one of the `wait.until` because the element you're waiting for never shows up... Did you check whether in the chrome instance you're connected in WhatsApp web or whether the website shows the QR code?

Comment: Line 30 means input_box_contact = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH, x_arg_contact)))

Comment: don't swallow exceptions

Comment: can you please explain more.